# Algebra confusion: $A^2 + B^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So i am currently trying to solve a practice question and i have hit a stump.

> The first term of a GP is $1$ and the sum of the third and fifth term is $90$. Find the common ratio.

Using $T_n = a \cdot r^{n-1}$ I got that $a = 1$

Hence

$ar^2 + ar^4 = 90 \implies r^2 + r^4 = 90$

But this is where i got stumped. The answer is given as $ \pm \;3$

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `\pm` produces $\pm$. Note that $R^2 + R^4 = R^2(1+R^2)$, so how can you write $90 = a\cdot(a+1)$?

Comment: Latex: $\large\pm$ is $\large\tt\mbox{\pm}$ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the equation $R^2+R^4=90$  If we define $x=R^2$ this becomes $x+x^2=90$, which is a quadratic and you solve it by the usual techniques.  But then you have to take the square root of $x$ to get $R$ and it can be either sign.

Comment: Thank you, you guys helped me a huge amount

Answer (score 3):

All of your calculations are right. We find ourselves needing to solve $r^2+r^4=90$.

Rearranging gives $r^4+r^2-90=0$. This can be thought of as a quadratic in $r^2$. Let $y=r^2$ then $y^2=r^4$ and so $r^4+r^2-90=0$ becomes $y^2+y-90=0$.

It turns out that $y^2+y-90$ factorises to gives $(y-9)(y+10)$.

Since $y$ was shorthand for $r^2$ we see that $r^4+r^2-90 \equiv (r^2-9)(r^2+10)$.

The solutions to $(r^2-9)(r^2+10) =0$ are $r^2=9$ and $r^2 = -10$. The equation $r^2=9$ has solutions $r=\pm 3$, while the equation $r^2=-10$ has no real solutions.